# Bootstrap-tagsinput breaks .input-group

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I'm using the otherwise excellent [bootstrap-tagsinput](https://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) in my app, but when I try to combine it with a Bootstrap 3 `input-group`, the input-group breaks.

Is there a way to fix this?

**jsFiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/cp5Lvtdo/2/

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code:**

```
<form id="defaultForm" method="post" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Cities</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="cities" id="aa" class="form-control" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" />
                <div class="input-group-addon">
                    Addon text
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-lg-3 control-label">Cities</label>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="cities" id="aa" class="form-control" value="Amsterdam,Washington,Sydney,Beijing,Cairo" data-role="tagsinput" />
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary input-group-btn'>
                    Button text
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to do is add this css for your input group

```
.input-group .bootstrap-tagsinput {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1px;
}
```

Then change your button code to look like this

```
<span class='input-group-btn'>
                <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>
                    Button text
                </button>
                </span>
```

Here's your fiddle with these changes http://jsfiddle.net/cp5Lvtdo/3/